# jQuery - Selector for duplicate ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with duplicate ID's for a form element.  The catch is I the elements show up separately based on a toggle. So both ID's never show up simultaneously.

However when I do form validation on that element, it always selects the element displayed last in the code (even if its hidden).

Is there a selector to select the visible duplicate ID?

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
$('#my_element:visible').val();
```

Comment: Have you tried not()?
 `$('#my_element').not(':hidden').val();`

Also, is there a reason you can't use class names instead of IDs since, IDs are technically for a single element on a page that is never repeated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: rename duplicate id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996680/jquery-rename-duplicate-id)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the myriad of other questions about this premise will tell you, you cannot use the ID selector `#` in this case; you have to use something like `$('div[id=foo]')` to find it.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I understand that using duplicate ID's are invalid however, the other element is display:none based on the toggle.   Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "This worked perfectly" sounds like it worked in one browser in one version or maybe several browsers in all or some existing versions. The spec does NOT allow duplicates if only one is visible, YOU CAN"T HAVE DUPLICATES. Hacks like this are a bad idea. If nothing else they lead to broken web sites and bloated and slow browsers working around all the broken code out in the world. Don't be that guy.

Comment: @Mike, I completely agree... however, sometimes a hack is necessary to meet a business requirement. I'm using an analytics tag manager to overlay script on top of a website whose code I don't control, that has horribly violated the don't duplicate ids rule - and worse, they didn't use any classes, leaving no other way to properly select the group of elements with jQuery. Documentation on hacks that work is still good and useful to the community; you really never know all the possible valid use cases for hacks. I didn't upvote this answer because the OP ought to use a HTML-compliant solution.

Comment: is there any performance set back that comes with using a selector like this? I would assuming using #foo is faster, but is it by much?

Comment: That syntax won't get you what you want because it only selects one thing. This question was about multiple items with the same ID. Although, ideally, you would just avoid duplicate IDs and use the #id selector.

Answer (score 11):

Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML and will nearly always cause issues with scripting. Avoid if at all possible.

Comment: Visible or not, you violate the spec and cause problems when duplicate IDs are in the DOM. Instead, use class names or other attributes to identify and work with your elements. The only spec-compliant way to keep using ID in your case is to actually remove one node and then place the other node into the DOM so that only one exists at a time.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is occurring is because of Duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique for the HTML to be considered valid. Whenever you aren't working against valid HTML, your results are often erratic.

In this case, even though you are only showing one of the forms at a time, they're both still present in the mark up which is why the last one in the code is always the one that's getting run.

Since you're using jQuery, I'd highly recommend using classes for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid duplicates ids on the page. It is not a valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

as Rwwl said, duplicate IDs are invalid.  Assign classes instead of ids to them.

Then you can do

```
alert($('.my_element:visible').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

try [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
   $("#my_element").find(":hidden").val();
```

Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

```
They have a CSS display value of none.
They are form elements with type="hidden".
Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
```

**NOTE:** Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible,

Comment: Even if this works in one case/browser/version I think it is a bad idea and could break in the future or other browsers. You are venturing into the realm of undefined behaviour in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use same id for multiple elements, classes are better!

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify using the # id selector only, you need to be more specific. One way is choose the type of element first then id:

For an input element:

```
$('input#my_element:visible').val();
```

or for a div element:

```
$('div#my_element:visible').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to select the element with jQuery and then get value from from the element directly:

```
$('#my_element:visible')[0].value
```