# Is there a difference between display: none and actually not writing the markup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an index page, which has the following child div (populated at runtime, if that matters):

```
<div id="editProductContainer" class="collapse" data-bind="with: ItemForEditing">
    @Html.Action("Edit", "Products")
</div>
```

Which after rendering looks like:

```
<div id="editProductContainer" class="collapse" data-bind="with: ItemForEditing"> 
  <div id="showChildContainer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 40%;">
       <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 23px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="panel panel-success">
                ...
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When calling bootstrap's `.modal('show')` on the modal it works as expected, popping up where it should. However, if I add another div in the index page above this one, as so:

```
<div style="display: none" id="viewProductContainer" class="collapse">
  <div id="showChildContainer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 40%;">
       <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 23px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="panel panel-success">
                ...
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="editProductContainer" class="collapse">
  <div id="showChildContainer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 40%;">
       <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 23px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="panel panel-success">
                ...
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This causes the modal in the first div to work correctly (if made visible), and the one in the 2nd div will only show the backdrop (the gray-ish background), without actually showing the modal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
Well of course there is! The `div`'s elements get rendered, together with their `ID`s, which will count when jQuerylooks for the first element with ID `showChildContainer`. But then, how can I get around this? I am making sure the two IDs are never visible together.

Comment: Voted to close as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I initially thought my problem was the one in the title, then realized it was another one that I didn't know how to solve, and then got answer for. Not sure what I'm supposed to do in this case. I voted for close aswell.

Comment: I suggest you edit your initial question's title with how you answered (since no one yet have answered it but you), then adjust your own answer a little by taking out the quote and write a small explanation and keep the link you added .. when that's done I will undo my down votes ... just drop me a message here when you are done

Answer (score -2):

After all, the question was "how to deal with duplicate IDs, when knowing both will not show up at the same time". The answer is here: [jQuery - Selector for duplicate ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850471/jquery-selector-for-duplicate-ids)

Comment: Duplicate id's is invalid and even if you can find them, one should still not use it, also, the question was _Is there a difference between display: none and actually not writing the markup?_