# jQuery add click function to multiple input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a function that responds to a click on each instance of an input field.  But the function only responds to a click on the first instance of the input.

The HTML is:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
     <td><input id="show-output" type="button" value=261 /></td>
     <td>mhour test202</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input id="show-output" type="button" value=260 /></td>
     <td>mhour test145</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The function is

```
$('#show-output').click(function(e) {
  alert("hi");
});
```

[A fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/SailingSteve/5Ljxq0of/17/)

Comment: Use classes to group elements. `id` can only refer to unique elements

Comment: You should use an id only once per page. Use a class here and it will work

Comment: A workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850569/2804966

Comment: @lalo it's a workaround that you should never use though. You should be fixing the source of the problem instead of hacking around it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ids to classes, as an id should always appear just once on a page.

```js
$('.show-output').click(function(e) {
  alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
     <td><input class="show-output" type="button" value=261 /></td>
     <td>mhour test202</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input class="show-output" type="button" value=260 /></td>
     <td>mhour test145</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```