# Why Html.Hidden is not working in C# ASP.NET MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to populate hidden inputs for a form using foreach in my razor view. It is like this:

```
@foreach (var commodity in ((FilterViewModel)ViewBag.ViewModel).commodities)
{
    Html.Hidden("commodities", commodity);
}
```

and here is my ViewModel:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string commodityType { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string repository { get; set; }
    public string[] commodities { get; set; }
    public string[] purchaseReportTypes { get; set; }
    public string dateValue_1 { get; set; }
    public string dateValue_2 { get; set; }
}
```

Although foreach lopps through items, hidden inputs are not added to my HTML source after rendering. However this one is working just fine and I don't know why `Html.Hidden` not works:

```
@foreach (var commodity in ((FilterViewModel)ViewBag.ViewModel).commodities)
{
    <input type="hidden" id="commodities" name="commodities" value="@commodity" />
}
```

Comment: Do you have a ToString implementation on the FilterViewModel. Try putting commodity.commodityType (or any of the string properties) in the method call. In the working code what value gets set?

Comment: Having multiple identical values for`id` in your html may cause problems.

Comment: @PeterSmith I guess select pickers do the same thing but may be I'm wrong!

Comment: There are plenty of answers which warn against the perils of multiple identical IDs; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850471/jquery-selector-for-duplicate-ids/6850498) for example. Try using `class` instead,

Comment: I've added an alternate answer which avoids the problem of mulitple identical IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a `@` before the `Html.Hidden`

```
@foreach (var commodity in ((FilterViewModel)ViewBag.ViewModel).commodities)
{
    @Html.Hidden("commodities", commodity);
}
```

By the way you should consider not having the same id in your html to avoid any problem.

Comment: What does @ does/means here? And why compiler did not prompt for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the multiple identical id values problem try the following (not tested):

```
@int idCount = 0;
@foreach (var commodity in ((FilterViewModel)ViewBag.ViewModel).commodities)
{
    idCount++;
    @Html.Hidden($"commodities{idCount}", commodity, new { @class="commodities"});
}
```

Use a jQuery selector with `.commodities` instead of `#commodities`.