# jquery show() property doesn't work on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 forms : FormA and FormB

```
<input id="submit"  type="submit"  value= "FormA" />

<input id="submit"  type="submit"  value= "FormB" />
```

when either one of the form is submitted, I want this button to appear on screen:

Click button

I tried using jquery. here is  the code:

```
$(function () {
        $("#submit").on('click', function () {
            $("#redirect").show();
        });
    });
```

However this only works when formA is submitted.
Am I missing something?
How can I make it work for both formA and formB
Help would be greatly appreciated
Good day people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Selector for duplicate ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850471/jquery-selector-for-duplicate-ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have 2 elements with same id `submit`, ids should be unique

> However this only works when formA is submitted.

`$("#submit")` will return only the first submit button

Either use different ids for each form or target will a class selector.

Try something like this

```
<input id="submitA"  type="submit"  value= "FormA" />    
<input id="submitB"  type="submit"  value= "FormB" />

$(function () {
        $("#submitA, #submitB").on('click', function () {
            $("#redirect").show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

id selector should be unique. you can change id selector to class selector

```
<input class="submit"  type="submit"  value= "FormA" />

<input class="submit"  type="submit"  value= "FormB" />

$(function () {
   $(".submit").on('click', function () {
     $("#redirect").show();
   });
});
```