# Jquery: dynamic change anchor data-attr if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a tiny jQuery function to add an id to each header (for the sake of using as anchor in a TOC).

```
$(":header").each(function() {
    let eachID = $(this)
    .text()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^\w ]+/g, "")
    .replace(/ +/g, "-");
    $(this).attr({ id: eachID });
});
```

It works as needed. 
`<h1>Hello World</h1>` becomes `<h1 id="hello-world">Hello World</h1>`.

I am having trouble with possible repeated/duplicated headers.

I found many answers on SO and the closest is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996680/jquery-rename-duplicate-id).

The small trouble with that one is that it adds a +1 to all headers after the first and not just the duplicated one.

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/persianphilosopher/pen/OEvpWP?editors=0010), you can see that `<h2>Hello World</h2>` is properly changed to `<h2 id="hello-world2">Hello World</h2>`, but so is `<h1>So long World</h1>`, even though it does not need to be changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is because you are iterating over all the `:header` elements in general and not looking for a specific id to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way around it using `document.querySelectorAll` ( `$(idSelector)` always returns the first element with the id as `ids` are supposed to be unique on a page anyways ) to get list of elements with a particular `id` and check for its length.

**Ideally you would not want to do that**.

```
$(':header[id]').not(':eq(0)').each(function(i){ 
    var $that = $(this);
      var currentId = $that.attr('id');
      var elemsWithId = document.querySelectorAll('#' + currentId);

      if(elemsWithId.length > 1) {
         var newID = currentId + (i + 1);
         $that.attr('id', newID);
      }
});
```

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyqWKB?editors=0010)**

Comment: Thanks so much. I know better than to assign ids to multiple elements on a page on my end but this project works with parsed markdown-notes to html and I can't force the notes to have unique headers. So this helps a lot. Thank you.